# Integration of Require along React with Flux

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have an application with the combination of `React JS` and `Require JS`. Now in the same application I am trying to extend the same application by integrating it with `Flux`. As per the tutorials I have gone through, I came to know that I have to use `Dispatcher.js` and `invariant.js`. Using `Require JS` I have loaded both the files, and I am trying to create the object of `Dispatcher` but I am getting different errors in different browsers.

```
define(["react", "dispatcher","invariant"],
   function(React, Dispatcher,invariant) {
    var demo1 = React.createClass({
        componentWillMount: function() {
            var AppDispatcher = new Dispatcher();
            console.log("Inside compnentDidMount");

        },
        render :function() {
            return (
                <div id="demoHeader">
                    <h1>Header of the application</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }),

    PageLayout = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <HeaderContainer />
                </div>
            );
        }
    })
    return PageLayout;
});
```

Because of below errors, I am not able to load my Dispatcher.js and Invariant.js files itself.

```
Firefox: 
    SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier (Dispatcher.js line: 107)
    ReferenceError: module is not defined (Invariant.js line: 53)

Chrome: 
    Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined (Invariant.js line: 53)
    Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined (Dispatcher.js line: 247)
```

Code for Dispatcher.js is:

```js
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 *
 * @providesModule Dispatcher
 * @typechecks
 * @preventMunge
 */

"use strict";

var invariant = require('./invariant');

var _prefix = 'ID_';

/**
 * Dispatcher is used to broadcast payloads to registered callbacks. This is
 * different from generic pub-sub systems in two ways:
 *
 *   1) Callbacks are not subscribed to particular events. Every payload is
 *      dispatched to every registered callback.
 *   2) Callbacks can be deferred in whole or part until other callbacks have
 *      been executed.
 *
 * For example, consider this hypothetical flight destination form, which
 * selects a default city when a country is selected:
 *
 *   var flightDispatcher = new Dispatcher();
 *
 *   // Keeps track of which country is selected
 *   var CountryStore = {country: null};
 *
 *   // Keeps track of which city is selected
 *   var CityStore = {city: null};
 *
 *   // Keeps track of the base flight price of the selected city
 *   var FlightPriceStore = {price: null}
 *
 * When a user changes the selected city, we dispatch the payload:
 *
 *   flightDispatcher.dispatch({
 *     actionType: 'city-update',
 *     selectedCity: 'paris'
 *   });
 *
 * This payload is digested by `CityStore`:
 *
 *   flightDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
 *     if (payload.actionType === 'city-update') {
 *       CityStore.city = payload.selectedCity;
 *     }
 *   });
 *
 * When the user selects a country, we dispatch the payload:
 *
 *   flightDispatcher.dispatch({
 *     actionType: 'country-update',
 *     selectedCountry: 'australia'
 *   });
 *
 * This payload is digested by both stores:
 *
 *   CountryStore.dispatchToken = flightDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
 *     if (payload.actionType === 'country-update') {
 *       CountryStore.country = payload.selectedCountry;
 *     }
 *   });
 *
 * When the callback to update `CountryStore` is registered, we save a reference
 * to the returned token. Using this token with `waitFor()`, we can guarantee
 * that `CountryStore` is updated before the callback that updates `CityStore`
 * needs to query its data.
 *
 *   CityStore.dispatchToken = flightDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
 *     if (payload.actionType === 'country-update') {
 *       // `CountryStore.country` may not be updated.
 *       flightDispatcher.waitFor([CountryStore.dispatchToken]);
 *       // `CountryStore.country` is now guaranteed to be updated.
 *
 *       // Select the default city for the new country
 *       CityStore.city = getDefaultCityForCountry(CountryStore.country);
 *     }
 *   });
 *
 * The usage of `waitFor()` can be chained, for example:
 *
 *   FlightPriceStore.dispatchToken =
 *     flightDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
 *       switch (payload.actionType) {
 *         case 'country-update':
 *         case 'city-update':
 *           flightDispatcher.waitFor([CityStore.dispatchToken]);
 *           FlightPriceStore.price =
 *             getFlightPriceStore(CountryStore.country, CityStore.city);
 *           break;
 *     }
 *   });
 *
 * The `country-update` payload will be guaranteed to invoke the stores'
 * registered callbacks in order: `CountryStore`, `CityStore`, then
 * `FlightPriceStore`.
 */
class Dispatcher {
  constructor() {
    this._lastID = 1;
    this._callbacks = {};
    this._isPending = {};
    this._isHandled = {};
    this._isDispatching = false;
    this._pendingPayload = null;
  }

  /**
   * Registers a callback to be invoked with every dispatched payload. Returns
   * a token that can be used with `waitFor()`.
   *
   * @param {function} callback
   * @return {string}
   */
  register(callback) {
    var id = _prefix + this._lastID++;
    this._callbacks[id] = callback;
    return id;
  }

  /**
   * Removes a callback based on its token.
   *
   * @param {string} id
   */
  unregister(id) {
    invariant(
      this._callbacks[id],
      'Dispatcher.unregister(...): `%s` does not map to a registered callback.',
      id
    );
    delete this._callbacks[id];
  }

  /**
   * Waits for the callbacks specified to be invoked before continuing execution
   * of the current callback. This method should only be used by a callback in
   * response to a dispatched payload.
   *
   * @param {array<string>} ids
   */
  waitFor(ids) {
    invariant(
      this._isDispatching,
      'Dispatcher.waitFor(...): Must be invoked while dispatching.'
    );
    for (var ii = 0; ii < ids.length; ii++) {
      var id = ids[ii];
      if (this._isPending[id]) {
        invariant(
          this._isHandled[id],
          'Dispatcher.waitFor(...): Circular dependency detected while ' +
          'waiting for `%s`.',
          id
        );
        continue;
      }
      invariant(
        this._callbacks[id],
        'Dispatcher.waitFor(...): `%s` does not map to a registered callback.',
        id
      );
      this._invokeCallback(id);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Dispatches a payload to all registered callbacks.
   *
   * @param {object} payload
   */
  dispatch(payload) {
    invariant(
      !this._isDispatching,
      'Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.'
    );
    this._startDispatching(payload);
    try {
      for (var id in this._callbacks) {
        if (this._isPending[id]) {
          continue;
        }
        this._invokeCallback(id);
      }
    } finally {
      this._stopDispatching();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Is this Dispatcher currently dispatching.
   *
   * @return {boolean}
   */
  isDispatching() {
    return this._isDispatching;
  }

  /**
   * Call the callback stored with the given id. Also do some internal
   * bookkeeping.
   *
   * @param {string} id
   * @internal
   */
  _invokeCallback(id) {
    this._isPending[id] = true;
    this._callbacks[id](this._pendingPayload);
    this._isHandled[id] = true;
  }

  /**
   * Set up bookkeeping needed when dispatching.
   *
   * @param {object} payload
   * @internal
   */
  _startDispatching(payload) {
    for (var id in this._callbacks) {
      this._isPending[id] = false;
      this._isHandled[id] = false;
    }
    this._pendingPayload = payload;
    this._isDispatching = true;
  }

  /**
   * Clear bookkeeping used for dispatching.
   *
   * @internal
   */
  _stopDispatching() {
    this._pendingPayload = null;
    this._isDispatching = false;
  }
}

module.exports = Dispatcher;
```

Code of Invariant.js is:

```js
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 *
 * @providesModule invariant
 */

"use strict";

/**
 * Use invariant() to assert state which your program assumes to be true.
 *
 * Provide sprintf-style format (only %s is supported) and arguments
 * to provide information about what broke and what you were
 * expecting.
 *
 * The invariant message will be stripped in production, but the invariant
 * will remain to ensure logic does not differ in production.
 */

var invariant = function(condition, format, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  }

  if (!condition) {
    var error;
    if (format === undefined) {
      error = new Error(
        'Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment ' +
        'for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.'
      );
    } else {
      var args = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
      var argIndex = 0;
      error = new Error(
        'Invariant Violation: ' +
        format.replace(/%s/g, function() { return args[argIndex++]; })
      );
    }

    error.framesToPop = 1; // we don't care about invariant's own frame
    throw error;
  }
};

module.exports = invariant;
```

If someone provide any example with the combination of Require, React and Flux that's really helpful.

Comment: You haven't showed the Invariant or Dispatcher code where the errors come from

Comment: Those two are the JS files that I have downloaded from GitHub. I have modified the post by adding those two files. Please have a look into it.

Comment: `module.exports` is CommonJS format, not AMD (RequireJS), so it is undefined. I recommend using webpack using CommonJS with babelJS or JSX instead.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. What you said is correct, i have modified DispatcherJS and InvariantJS according to require syntax by importing using "define(["invariant"], function(invariant) {})" and returned Dispatcher and invariant from respective files. Now I am getting a different error as "SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier" at line 108 in Dispatcher.js. Is there any specific things that I have to follow to get rid of this error?

Comment: @user1977438 it's ES6, you need to use babel to convert it to ES5. The react community leans heavily towards commonjs, so if you're going to use amd, be prepared for an uphill battle. As a side note, everything amd offers is available in webpack (I think).